# wifi p2p between ubuntu 14.04 and android

Tags: linux, ubuntu, android, p2p

I attempted to make a wifi p2p connection between Ubuntu 14.04(kernel 3.13) and Android 4.4 Kitkat(Samsung Galaxy Note 2)

**In Ubuntu**
I use wpa_supplicant v2.1 which is built in to Ubuntu 14.04(`/sbin/wpa_supplicant`) and Netis WF2120 wifi dongle(rtl8192cu chipset).
Ubuntu is group owner.

The following is my execute sequence in Ubuntu.

1. After Ubuntu was booted, I allocate an IP address(`192.168.22.1`) to wlan2 interface to use p2p(Netis wifi dongle).
2. Run **dhcpd wlan2** command
3. Run **wpa_cli** command to connect **wpa_supplicant**, which runs in boot time (meaning I did not run **wpa_supplicant** myself)
4. Run **p2p_group_add** command in **wpa_cli** prompt
5. Generate new wps pin number using **wps_pin any** command

Then wait for Android peer connection

**In Android**

1. Run built in wifi direct app and find peer, then find Ubuntu peer without problems.
2. Connect to Ubuntu peer with pin number which is generated by the **wps_pin any** command

Then connect to Ubuntu without any issues.
I confirm that Android has received the IP address(`192.168.22.100`) from Ubuntu's dhcpd,
so ping test is also normal.

The problem is Ubuntu and Android are connected to each other, but then after a few seconds(within 10s), Android's wifi turns off automatically and wifi p2p is disconnected.

I think problem is in Ubuntu.

So I was ran **wpa_supplicant** directly with my config file.

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
device_name=testest
device_type=1-0050F204-1
p2p_go_intent=15
```

and then I ran this next command

```
wpa_supplicant -Dnl80211 -c <config file path> -i wlan2 -dt
```

But the result is the same.

Is there any problem in my configuration?
Or any other problem?

Comment: hardware/OS, not SW

Comment: Hi, this is a long shot, but do you have any update? I'm trying to basically do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The group needs to be created as a persistent group so that your connection doesn't drop. You should be able to do that in the autonomous GO scenario with 
`p2p_group_add persistent`.

In the negotiated GO scenario try:

`p2p_connect <peer device address> <pbc|pin|PIN#|p2ps> [display|keypad|p2ps] persistent go_intent=15`

See the wpa_supplicant README-P2P for further details: 
https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/wpa_supplicant/README-P2P.